# Intuitive Sortable and Draggable UI indicators

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got elements which i can sort and elements which I can drag and drop into container and back. How should I show to users that some elements can be sorted and some of them are draggable (so I also need to show drop area, which I can just highlight while dragging)?

In [jQuery Sortable UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) demo I see double-arror indicator, on some sites there are two column dotted dash.

Share your experience, please

- [Some draggable examples](http://www.google.ru/search?um=1&hl=ru&newwindow=1&biw=1364&bih=978&site=search&tbs=isz%3Ai&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=draggable&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)
- [Some sortable examples](http://www.google.ru/search?um=1&hl=ru&newwindow=1&biw=1364&bih=978&site=search&tbs=isz%3Ai&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sortable&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, at this stage at least, is that dynamic-reordering of lists, etc. is a relatively new concept for most people... there doesn't seem to be any real convention surrounding the issue, as there is for more established interactions like buttons, checkboxes, etc.

I would tend to suggest that anything that represents that the item might be 'grab-able' or 'sortable' would be an excellent idea.  Arrows work, as do the ridged handles on iOS (three horizontal, inset bars) - but neither is inherently obvious.  As always, real-world mapping is the ideal here... but as practically everything in the 'real world' is manipulable, it makes the task rather more difficult.  There's nothing that truly maps from the real world to a UI to show 'ability to be dragged'.

Whatever you decide to use, you're probably going to have to provide some advice to your end-user on what the symbols mean (perhaps a tool-tip, or a simple once-off notification)... as it's not always immediately obvious.  Personally, I'd probably go with the JQuery-style arrows to show the list as sortable (but it still doesn't really highlight the possibility of a drag interaction... do I click the arrows to move them, or do I click and drag, or is there some other mechanism?).

Comment: Using mouse pointer (as hand, finger etc) can be helpfull with image indicators and tips. Thanx for your answer

Comment: True enough - but the 'hand pointer' is also used for links in common web-based UIs, so that *might* further reinforce a click-based use-case, rather than a drag-based use-case.  An *ideal* scenario would be to be able to implement an "open" hand icon, when over something that's draggable... which turns into a "grasping" hand during the process of dragging.

Comment: I mean this one http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/images/cursor-openhand.png and this one while dragging http://www.washington.edu/lst/help/documentation/powerpoint2007/images/hand.jpg Actually you are talking about the same thing :)

Comment: Fair enough - then looks like we're thinking the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

For marking up drop area's I always use the `start` option of the draggable for adding a class, for deleting the class I use the `stop` option. Something like this:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $('.droppable').addClass('droppableArea');
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('.droppable').removeClass('droppableArea');
    },
});
```

When dragging a file, a hover class is always nice on the droppable:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    over: function() {
        $(this).addClass('droppableHover');
    },
    out: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('droppableHover');
    }
});
```

And your css:

```
.droppableArea {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.droppableHover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can check it out in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hvFHM/)

Comment: This is good approach. But how should user understand that your `Testing` string is draggable. I am interested in visual indication for making interfaces more intuitive

Comment: That's always hard and I'm not good at UI at all.. What I would come up with is http://jsfiddle.net/hvFHM/2/ but the css is bad and it looks kind of ugly... Designing is not my thing I'm sorry!

Comment: It is better to show crossarrow constantly, that indicates that that thing is draggable